# mysql allow remote root special characters

Tags: mysql, centos

I'm trying to have `!!` in my password for mysql remote login but it won't take it when I execute the following command:

```
grant all on *.* root@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '1234c00l!!';
```

It's telling me that I have a syntax error. Is there any other way to allow remote login with password with special characters? Any kind of help I can get on this is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You *do* have a syntax error, but it's not with the exclamation points.

You're missing [`TO`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/grant.html):

```
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO root@'%' ...
```